# How to install Blender in a version of your choice using the command line?

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, software-installation

I have Blender 2.69, this is the version I got when I typed

```
sudo apt-get install Blender
```

in the command line.

I do not know if this version is stable, but maybe it is the reason why a part of Blender does not work properly. Therefore I would like to install another version, maybe 2.68.

Is it possible to specify the version number of a program when installing it using the command line ?

Comment: Which distribution do you use?

Comment: linux mint 17.1 rebecca

Comment: This distribution is based on Ubuntu 14.04 which also uses blender 2.69 and I can't find any backports. I don't think there is an easy way to solve your problem.

Comment: I do not know the term backport, would it hypothetically work if i would install blender 2.68 or another version from source ?

Answer (score 1):

You can install packages from other releases (even other distros like Debian):

```
apt-get install -t experimental blender
```

experimental can be sid, stable, testing...

Check

```
man apt-get | less +/--target-release
```

This requires to modify `/etc/apt/sources.list` to add another release